# elliptic pde with supercritical advection term

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $B$ denote the unit ball in $ R^N$ centered at the origin and consider 
$$ -\Delta u(x) + \frac{ x \cdot \nabla u(x)}{|x|^\alpha} = f(x) \quad \mbox{ in } B$$ with $u=0$ on $ \partial B$.    (or instead work on an annulus $ \Omega_\epsilon:=\{x \in B:  |x|>\epsilon\})$.   Here $ \alpha>2$.  Here $ f$ is bounded.  I seem to be able to get estimates like $ |u(x)| \le C |x|^\alpha$.

QUESTION.  Can one expect to get the natural gradient estimate $ | \nabla u(x)| \le C |x|^{\alpha-1}$.